# The parity of a pair of electrons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, textbook-erratum

In the page 254 of Scrednicki's QFT book, it states that a pair of electrons also has negative intrinsic parity. But I think the parity of two identical particles must be one. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: Second line is unclear...edit it please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intrinsic parity of a pair of particles is the product of the intrinsic parities of the particles.  The convention is that that matter particles have positive parity and antiparticles have negative parity, so a pair of matter particles should have positive intrinsic parity.

However that's not quite the entire story, because electrons must obey the exclusion principle: the total electron wavefunction must be antisymmetric under exchange.  The antisymmetry is established in the angular momentum sector. If the two electrons' spins are configured as a spin singlet, the orbital angular momentum $L$ between them must be even; if the electrons form a spin triplet, $L$ must be odd.  The parity of the orbital angular momentum wavefunctions is $(-1)^L$, so the total parity of an electron pair depends on the total spin.

This answer is different from your textbook ([draft online](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html)).
The difference between his argument and mine seems to come from equation 40.15, where the parity transformation on the Dirac spinor introduces a phase factor $i\beta$ for matrix $\beta = \left(\array{0&I\\I&0}\right)$; the negative intrinsic parity for the particle-antiparticle pair comes from $(i\beta)^2=-I$.  A full explanation probably involves something sneaky with Weyl spinors.  Why not try following the derivation in equations 40.10–40.17 for a particle pair instead of an antiparticle pair?

Comment: When I go through this chapter, I think that the book assumes that the intrinsic parity of the particles and antiparticles are both $-i$, and it seems very strange.

Comment: I suspect it's $i\beta$, above, because of something to do with particles and antiparticles transforming to each other under CP.

Comment: Ok,I maybe check other textbooks to find more examples on intrinsic parity. Thank you for your help.